# Rmarkdown large empty space between footnote and page end

Tags: r, r-markdown, footnotes

I added a footnote and now the page looks like this. How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
header-includes:
    - \usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
```

Blank space is before the footnote now.

It looks like since I have a subsection next, it doesn't fit the on the same page, which is odd, since there clearly is enough space for text...